# What is the difference between `this instanceof String` and `"foo" instanceof String`?

Tags: javascript

I'm extending Object like this:

```
Object.prototype.is_a = function (x) {
  return this instanceof x;
}
```

All works as expected

```
"foo".is_a(String) // true
"foo".is_a(Object) // true
"foo".is_a(Array) // false
"foo".is_a(Function) // false
"foo".is_a(Boolean) // false
"foo".is_a(Date) // false
"foo".is_a(Number) // false
"foo".is_a(RegExp) // false
```

but, when

```
"foo" instanceof String // false
```

`this` keyword on the `is_a()` function is same as `foo` right? Why does it return different results?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I have a bias, so I could be wrong. But, I'm not sure this is a duplicate. There's overlap, but this is also about [boxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Boxing) rather than just `instanceof` with primitives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you cannot apply `instanceof` to primitive values, that's why

```
"foo" instanceof String
```

returns `false`. Primitives are not objects and hence cannot be an instance of a constructor function. *

**So why does it seem to work inside the `is_a` method?**

In non-strict mode, the value of `this` inside a function [is always going to be an object](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3) (step 3). If `this` value is not an object, it is implicitly converted to one. You can test this with `console.log(typeof this)`.
That means that the string primitive `"foo"` is converted to an String object `new String("foo")` and that's why you can use `instanceof` on it.

In strict mode, the value of `this` doesn't have to be an object and is not automatically converted ([step 1](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3)). Your method would fail in that case:

```
> Object.prototype.is_a = function (x) {
   'use strict';
   return this instanceof x;
 }
> "foo".is_a(String)
false
```

---

*: That's a very simplified explanation. In reality, the `instanceof` operator delegates the evaluation to the constructor function's internal [`[[HasInstance]]` method](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5.3), which is defined to return `false` if the passed value is not an object.

Answer (score 1):

String literals aren't the same as String objects ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects)).  It appears that the string literal (which is a string primitive) is automatically boxed into an object when it's used as the binding context of a function (i.e. when it's `this` inside a function):

```
>>> typeof "foo"
"string"
>>> Object.prototype.type_of = function (x) {
  return typeof this;
}
function (x) {
  return typeof this;
}
>>> "foo".type_of()
"object"
```

That explains your instanceof behavior, as well.  This behaves as you might expect:

```
>>> new String("foo") instanceof String
true
>>> new String("foo") instanceof Object
true
>>> new String("foo").is_a(String)
true
>>> new String("foo").is_a(Object)
true
>>> new String("foo").is_a(Array)
false
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has both primitive and object versions of strings, numbers and booleans. String literals define primitives rather than objects. If you did `typeof "foo"`, you would get "string" rather than "object". But when you access a property of the string, it creates a temporary String object from the primitive string and then accesses the corresponding property of *that object*, so it `this instanceof String` is true inside that temporary String object's method.

In order to test whether something is a string while accounting for both primitives and objects, you need to test `typeof foo === "string" || foo instanceof String`.

Answer (score 0):

instanceof needs an object defined, this example returns true:

```
var f = new String("foo");
alert( f instanceof String);
```

This is more similar to your example:

```
alert( new String("foo") instanceof String);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "type defined"?

Comment: an object type, new ObjectType(), shoot me I'm a java, c guy.  are you a parser?